# Slicing windows of size N from a list at each step

Tags: python, list

If I was to slice the following list, say with a step of 5, I could easily do:

```
l = list(range(20))
l[::5]
```

Giving:

```
[0, 5, 10, 15]
```

But what would be the easiest way to do the same but selecting centered windows of size 3 (or as many items as available) at each step? So:

```
[0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16]
```

For now I've bee trying something like:

```
[[l[i-1],l[i],l[i+1]] for i in l[::5][1:]]
```

Which is not even returning a flattened list.

Comment: This feels so confusing. Can you provide an explanation about that output? It just makes no sense.

Comment: why does it start off with just `[0,1..]` instead of 0 1 2 or something?

Comment: The output and description is very confusing

Comment: Because the windows are centered at each step. So at 0, the window is centered at 0, so oonly 0 and 1 are available. Whereas at 5, all 4,5 and 6 are available

Comment: that adds a few more problems. with a window of 4, should i get `0 1` at start or `0 1 2`? Why would the windows work off of centres instead of the start?

Comment: You can assume odd windows @ParitoshSingh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list slicing inside a list comprehension:

```
[y for i in range(0, len(l), 5) for y in l[max(i-1, 0):i+2]]
# [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16]
```

Generalizing, we have

```
window = 3 // 2
[y for i in range(0, len(l), 5) for y in l[max(i-window, 0):i+window+1]]
# [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16]
```

---

Another option using `itertools` `islice` and `chain`:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

list(chain.from_iterable(
    islice(l, max(i-1, 0), i+2) for i in range(0, len(l), 5)))
# [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: wau thanks :) Could it be done with a window parameter?

Comment: @user2362113 Sure, see edit. Just set `window = N // 2` and it will work.